# Copiar texto de uma tag e colar em um campo ao pressionar determinado botão

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde a todos! Galera tenho uma página personalizada de um portal captivo em um servidor pfSense. Nessa página existem filtros em php onde elementos da página são diferentes dependendo do resultado que o filtro em php traz, no caso o filtro tem como base endereços ips e mac address para funcionários e visitantes. Atualmente quando visitantes entram no wifi a página do portal aparece e existe um botão onde o visitante clica e o código voucher é automaticamente copiado de uma tag span  (o código é inserido na tag span por php, outra coisa!) e então a pessoa tem que colar o código no campo de inserção do voucher na página de login apertar o botão conectar. Isso já foi feito, vou por o cód aqui, entretanto gostaria de deixar mais automatizado rsrsrs para quando a pessoa clicar no botão de copiar o voucher o código copiado já fosse para o campo input do código voucher e também já fosse enviado o formulário para conexão. Segue o código atual bem simplificado:

#### Botão para visitante clicar e copiar o cód voucher:

clique `<a id="button2" href="#inp_voucher" style="color: #fdc501">`AQUI`</a>`

#### Tag com id 'cod-voucher' que recebe o cód voucher do php do pfSense:

```
<span id="cod-voucher" style="display: none">salsifrufru</span>
```

#### Cód que copia o voucher da tag span #cod-voucher quando o botão #button2 é pressionado:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#button2").click(function(){
                var texto = $("#cod-voucher").text();
                var $temp = $("<input>");
                $("body").append($temp);
                $temp.val(texto).select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
                $temp.remove();
                alert ("Código copiado! Agora cole no campo 'Código Voucher' e precione 'CONECTAR!'");
                });
        })
</script>
```

#### Input onde o visitante deve colar o código voucher copiado acima, observem que o input está com filtro de ip por php pois para quem não tem endereço ip de visitante (funcionários não devem usar voucher) este campo é desabilitado:

```
<?php
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if($ip=="192.168.0.95") {echo "<input name=\"auth_voucher\" type=\"text\" id=\"voucher\" placeholder=\"Voucher somente para visitantes!\" readonly=\"true\">"; }
        else { echo "<input name=\"auth_voucher\" type=\"text\" id=\"voucher\" placeholder=\"Código Voucher\">"; }
?>
```

#### Botão "submit" para conectar após colar o código voucher:

```
<div><button name="accept" type="submit" value="continue" class="submitform">CONECTAR!</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito, basta você fazer assim:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#button2").click(function(){
                var texto = $("#cod-voucher").text();
                var $temp = $("<input>");
                $("body").append($temp);
                $temp.val(texto).select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
                $temp.remove();

                $('#voucher').val(texto);
                });
        })
</script>
```

Só acrecentei `$('#voucher').val(texto);` dentro da sua função. O que essa linha faz é colocar o conteudo da variável `texto` dentro do valor referente ao elemento com `id = voucher`

Comment: Opa é isso mesmo Otavio, obrigado. Depois só precisei usar uma função pra fazer com q o mesmo botão ao ser clicado também disparasse o botão de conectar no form. Obrigado.